# Running Applet as Application main() instead of init()

Tags: java, applet, program-entry-point, init

Okay, so I'm creating a loader inside my jPanel for a .jar. The jar I'm loading has special code inside the main() so when I run the applet with init(), things get messed up. My current code looks like this

```
  public Applet getApplet() {
    try {
        classLoader = getClassLoader();

        if (classLoader != null) {
            Class<?> client = classLoader.loadClass(Constants.mainClass);

            Object instance = client.newInstance();
            applet = (Applet) instance;
            applet.setStub(new Stub());
            return applet;
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get it to load the the applet from the programs main()

How would I go about editing it so it loads the application in my jPanel by using main()

Comment: Won't calling `main()` from `init()` work?

Comment: I don't want to load the application separate from my application, since it's a loader it needs to run inside my application.

Comment: `ignore.printStackTrace();` Now there's irony. 'Ignoring' exception output is typically warned against and the advice offered is along the lines of *"At least **print the stack trace** so it is obvious what happened!"* ;)